# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, como resolver este error?

Tags: swift

Cuando ejecuto la aplicacion me sale este error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value en esta la linea del codigo:

```
for valor in resultado["results"] as! [NSDictionary]{
```

Este es el codigo completo:

```
class LeerNoticias{


    func getNoticias(termino: @escaping (_ datos:[String])->()){
    let session = URLSession.shared
      let liga = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostviewed/arts/30.json?api-key=029bb2ef5c76452bac5b2c3ca06893dd"
      let url = URL(string: liga)!
        let _:Void = session.dataTask(with: url) { (dato:Data?, respuesta:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
            //var titulos:[String] = []
            do{
                let resultado = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dato!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
                var titulos:[String] = []
                for valor in resultado["results"] as! [NSDictionary]{
                  titulos.append(valor["title"] as! String)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                    termino(titulos)

                }
            }catch{
              print("Error en lectura")
            }
        }.resume()
        }

 }
```

Alguien tiene una idea como podria resolverlo?

Comment: Te he dejado la respuesta, ejecuté tu código y me dio error en la línea de **dato!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la data obtenida de esa url es **nil** o el servidor al que tratas de acceder está abajo. Lo que menciona Bicho es correcto, con el uso de guard puedes parar la ejecución del código si no se cumple una condición. Sin embargo, te sugiero que utilices **JSONDecoder()**, esto ayudará a evitar que el código truene si algún dato falta, además, puedes poner campos opcionales por si en algún momento solamente está faltando un campo la ejecución siga. Este es un ejemplo:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostviewed/arts/30.json?api-key=029bb2ef5c76452bac5b2c3ca06893dd") else {
    fatalError("could not create url")
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let jsonData = data else {
        return
    }
    do {
        let list = try JSONDecoder().decode(TuObjeto.self, from: jsonData)
        self.dataArray = list
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener mucho cuidado cuando trabajes con los **optionals** y necesites hacer **unwrap**. Para esto hay varias formas de hacer tu código seguro y que no haga crash con ese tipo de mensajes.

La manera más segura es utilizar `guard`:

```
guard let resultados = resultado["results"] else { return }

for valor in resultados as! [NSDictionary]{
    titulos.append(valor["title"] as! String)
}
```

De esta manera si `resultados` es `nil` no ejecuta las otras líneas de tu código y pasa al `else`.

Lo mismo puede pasar con `dato!`, que lo mandas a hacer unwrap directamente y cuando sea `nil` de igual manera te va a dar ese error.