# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

necesito ayuda cada que ejecuto el programa aparece el error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value en la linea 39
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese error sucede porque esta tratando de acceder a un valor nil, te recomiendo leer un poco de optional, evita usar el force unwapring(agregar ! al final de tus variables), en lugar de eso usa el optional binding

Comment: Agrega el código como texto. La mejor manera de evitar esos errores es utilizar `guard` te dejo el link para que te guíes: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/350330/154236